Custom Faker Providers still undefined methods while loading via singleton
Since L11 I've been encountering some issues with custom Faker providers which are working but are not recognised by Fake\Generator (PHPStan).
hereby my example:
So I've made a custom service provider called FakerServiceProvider.php:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Faker\Factory;
use Faker\Generator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Modules\Hrm\Database\Providers\CertificationFakerProvider;

class FakerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->singleton(
            abstract: Generator::class,
            concrete: function (): Generator {
                $factory = Factory::create();

                $factory->addProvider(new CertificationFakerProvider($factory));

                return $factory;
            }
        );
    }
}

I registered a singleton with as abstract class Faker\Generator, in concrete I added a callback function which will add my custom FakerProvider.
In my custom faker provider CertificationFakerProvider.php I've added all the public functions which I need and I extend from the Faker\Provider\Base class:
<?php

namespace Modules\Hrm\Database\Providers;

use Faker\Provider\Base;

class CertificationFakerProvider extends Base
{
    protected static array $certificationName = [
        [
            'en' => 'Physician',
            'nl' => 'Arts',
            'fr' => 'Médecin',
            'de' => 'Arzt',
        ],
        [
            'en' => 'Resident',
            'nl' => 'AIOS (arts in opleiding)',
            'fr' => 'Résident',
            'de' => 'Assistenzarzt',
        ],
       // ...
    ];

    /**
     * @example 'Physician'
     *
     * @param string $locale
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function certificationName(string $locale = 'en'): string
    {
        return static::randomElement(static::$certificationName)[$locale];
    }

    /**
     * @example ['en' => 'Physician', 'nl' => 'Arts', 'fr' => 'Médecin', 'de' => 'Arzt']
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function certificationNameAllLocales(): array
    {
        return static::randomElement(static::$certificationName);
    }
}

In my Laravel factory I use 1 of the methods via the global faker a attribute:
<?php

namespace Modules\Hrm\Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Modules\Hrm\Domains\Profile\Models\Certification;

/**
 * @extends Factory<Certification>
 */
class CertificationFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     */
    protected $model = Certification::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->certificationNameAllLocales(),
        ];
    }
}

What I did is:
Added the FakerServiceProvider class to the bootstrap/providers.php
I ran these commands:

php artisan optimize:clear
composer dump-autoload

Result:
For some reason my PHPstan is still not recognizing my custom side-loaded provider.
It keeps throwing this error on me:
 ------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Line   Hrm/database/factories/CertificationFactory.php                              
 ------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  26     Call to an undefined method Faker\Generator::certificationNameAllLocales().  
 ------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

meanwhile I've accomplished that my PHPSTORM recognises my provider (see screenshot), but I'd like to solve this the clean way instead of ignoring phpstan errors.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Or what I'm doing wrong?
When I dump $this->faker I see that Faker\Genrator has included CertificationFakerProvider. But for some reason PHPstand cannot handle this.
